# Discontinuous boundary condition distorts in the numeric solution

Tags: differential-equations, discontinuity

Here I want to simulate a physical model that I have used a set of differential equations.

My coefficients and parameters:

```
gamma=2*Pi*6.02*10^6; alpha= 20; L=4000; u=299792458;
detunp=0*gamma;detunc=0*gamma;detund=0*gamma; 
gamma21=0*gamma;gamma31=1.25*gamma;gamma41=1.25*gamma;
ch=150*Sqrt[2];cv=150*Sqrt[2];dh=1500*Sqrt[2];dv=1500*Sqrt[2];
Mu=70;Theta=2.45*Pi/180;
A=Exp[-2*(x^2+y^2)/100^2];
OmegaC=(0.3*gamma)*Exp[-2*(x^2/cv^2+(Mu+y Cos[Theta]+(z-L/2)Sin[Theta])^2/(ch^2(1-x^2/cv^2)))];
OmegaD=(0.3*gamma)*Exp[-2*(x^2/cv^2+(Mu+y Cos[Theta]+(z-L/2)Sin[Theta])^2/(ch^2(1-x^2/cv^2)))];
```

My partial differential equations and boundary conditions and solving:

```
pde={D[a[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*S[z,t]+0.5*I*OmegaD*c[z,t]+(I*detund-
0.5*gamma41)*a[z, t],D[b[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*P[z,t]+0.5*I*OmegaC*c[z,t]+(I*detunp-0.5*gamma31)*b[z, t],
D[c[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*b[z,t]*OmegaC+0.5*I*a[z,t]*OmegaD+(I*detunc-0.5*gamma21)*c[z, t],
D[P[z,t],z]+1/u*D[P[z,t],t]==I*alpha*gamma31/(2L)*b[z,t],
D[S[z,t],z]+1/u*D[S[z,t],t]==I*alpha*gamma41/(2L)*a[z,t]};

 bc={P[0,t]==A*Boole[10<=t<=30],P[z,0]==0,S[0,t]==S[z,0]==0,b[z,0]==a[z,0]==c[z,0]==0};

solns=ParametricNDSolve[{pde, bc}, {P, S, a, b, c}, {z, 0, 4000}, {t, 0, 60}, {x, y}];
```

As you can see, I have used a `Boole` function in `bc` to simulate the pulse shape of laser light.

But after solving the `solns`, I will get a distort pulse-shape like this.

```
Plot[{Evaluate[Sum[Abs[P[x,y][0,t]/.solns]^2,{x,0,0,3},{y,0,0,3}]]},
{t,0,60},PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Is that unavoidable?

Or is there any solutions can help me, thanks :)

Comment: Where's the definition of `OmegaD` etc.?

Comment: You got the graph with what code?

Comment: Ok, I added explanation for plotting part.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a bigger `"ScaleFactor"` inside `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"`, and a denser spatial grid to suppress the `eerr` warning:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines",
"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

solns = ParametricNDSolve[{pde, bc}, {P, S, a, b, c}, {z, 0, 4000}, {t, 0, 60}, {x, y}, 
   Method -> Union[mol[True, 20], mol[350, 4]]];

expr = Sum[Abs[P[x, y][0, t] /. solns]^2, {x, 0, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 0, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {2.499116, Null} *)

Plot[expr, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The information about `"ScaleFactor"` can be found in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1306392612).

---

To make this answer more complete, I'd like to mention, another possible solution for this problem is to use a smooth function that's very close to the original b.c. to simulate the pulse:

```
(* Approximate UnitStep *)
appro[x_] = With[{k = 1000}, ArcTan[k x]/Pi + 1/2];

bc = {P[0, t] == A*Boole[10 <= t <= 30], P[z, 0] == 0, S[0, t] == S[z, 0] == 0, 
     b[z, 0] == a[z, 0] == c[z, 0] == 0} /. 
    Boole -> (Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@Boole@# &) /. UnitStep -> appro;

solns2 = ParametricNDSolve[{pde, bc}, {P, S, a, b, c}, {z, 0, 4000}, {t, 0, 60}, {x, y}, 
   Method -> mol[350, 4]];

expr2 = Sum[Abs[P[x, y][0, t] /. solns2]^2, {x, 0, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 0, 3}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[expr2, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's a bit inferior to the former solution at least in this case, but still acceptable.

This alternative method can be useful when big `"ScaleFactor"` causes trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful assistance and other technique suggestions about my problem :) I've learned a lot from it!

Comment: Why can't I get the same result by your code above? (smooth function method) It shows that: `ParametricNDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`

Comment: @tablecircle Perhaps it's due to the buggy v10.0.1, I've tested the code in v9.0.1 and v11.0.1 (Wolfram Cloud), both output the result above without difficulty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzSqX.png