# Inhomogeneous dynamic Euler-Bernoulli beam equation with discontinuous parameters

Tags: differential-equations, discontinuity

The code

```
x0 = 0.25;  T = 20;   u1 = -0.03;  u2 = 0.07;  u3 = -0.04;
a = 1/100;   t0 = 5;  omega = 2;
a = 0.01;  dis[x_] := a/(Pi (x^2 + a^2))
P[t_] := If[t <= t0, Sin[omega t], 0]
u[t_] := u1 HeavisideTheta[t - 0.8] + 
  u2 HeavisideTheta[t - 1.64] + u3 HeavisideTheta[t - 3.33]

pde = a D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] + D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] - 
   P[t] dis[x - x0];
sol = NDSolve[{pde == 0, w[0, t] == u[t], w[1, t] == 0, 
    Derivative[2, 0][w][0, t] == 0, Derivative[2, 0][w][1, t] == 0, 
    w[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 0] == 0}, 
   w[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 80}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
```

gives an error

```
NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 246.5944594961422` at t = 80.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 25 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options.
```

I think it's because of the boundary conditions on derivatives. Have tried Automatic, MethodOfLines, etc., does not help. Tried

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MinPoints" -> 100}}
```

works fine with second order equation subjected to bc containing only first order derivative. Any thoughts, hints?

Answer (score 2):

`eerr` is a warning, not an error, it just suggests the possibility of trouble and doesn't always mean the output you obtained is wrong. Indeed, the solution given by `NDSolve` with the default setting seems to be erroneous, but according to my test, with a spatial grid **dense enough** e.g. `50` (BTW it seems to be better to use a **even** number), `NDSolve` won't give too bad a solution, even if the warning is still there:

```
appro = With[{k = 1000}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
unitStepExpand = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@# &;

x0 = 25/100; T = 20; u1 = -3/100; u2 = 7/100; u3 = -4/100;
a = 1/100; t0 = 5; omega = 2;
a = 1/100; dis[x_] := a/(Pi (x^2 + a^2))
P[t_] = unitStepExpand@If[t <= t0, Sin[omega t], 0];
u[t_] = u1 HeavisideTheta[t - 8/10] + u2 HeavisideTheta[t - 164/100] + 
    u3 HeavisideTheta[t - 333/100] /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep;

pde = a D[w[x, t], {x, 4}] + D[w[x, t], {t, 2}] - P[t] dis[x - x0];

(* I decrease the value of tend 
   because the solution seems to come to steady state long before 80. *)
tend = 10;

mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

fsol = NDSolveValue[{pde == 0, w[0, t] == u[t], w[1, t] == 0, 
      Derivative[2, 0][w][0, t] == 0, Derivative[2, 0][w][1, t] == 0, w[x, 0] == 0, 
      Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 0] == 0} /. UnitStep -> appro, w, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> mol[50, 4]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Plot[fsol[0, t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> .05]
Plot3D[fsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> 2, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}]
Manipulate[Plot[fsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> 2], {t, 0, tend}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image]

I modfied the parameters with the `appro` and `unitStepExapnd` because of the reason mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129280/1871).

Well, I admit there still exists slight yet suspicious oscillation in the solution, and obtaining a highly accurate numerical solution for the problem seems to be pending, so let's wait and see if someone will come up with a better approach.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, you are right, the oscillations are very suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe Mathematica can't solve the boundary condition on the second order derivative problem.(I'm not sure, waiting for other expert's answer!)
So, I tried to rewrite your code by defining `s[x, t] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]`

Therefore, your pde and bc becomes:

```
pde = {a D[s[x, t],{x, 2}]+D[w[x, t],{t, 2}]-P[t] dis[x- x0]==0,
       s[x, t] == D[w[x, t], {x, 2}]};
bc = {w[0, t] == u[t], w[1, t] == 0, s[0, t] == 0, s[1, t] == 0, 
      w[x, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][w][x, 0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, {s, w}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 80}];
Plot3D[w[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 80}]
```

with result:

[image]

Comment: I have also tried this, but it does not help.

Comment: "I think that maybe Mathematica can't solve the boundary condition on the second order derivative problem." Well, I don't think so, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127980/1871)'s a problem that is quite similar to OP's.

Comment: BTW, which version do you use? I just tested the code on Cloud but can't reproduce your result, only got the `(0,1) CoefficientArrays::poly:` warning.

Comment: I use Wolfram Mathematics 10.1.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful information, xzczd! I use version 10.0.1.0.