# How to avoid unnecessary calculations in a numerical simulation and improve performance?

Tags: differential-equations, simulation

Corresponding to the previous question I posted:
[Discontinuous boundary condition distorts in the numeric solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129230/discontinuous-boundary-condition-distorts-in-the-numeric-solution).

```
gamma=2*Pi*6.02*10^6; alpha= 20; L=4000; u=299792458;
detunp=0*gamma;detunc=0*gamma;detund=0*gamma; 
gamma21=0*gamma;gamma31=1.25*gamma;gamma41=1.25*gamma;
ch=150*Sqrt[2];cv=150*Sqrt[2];dh=1500*Sqrt[2];dv=1500*Sqrt[2];
Mu=70;Theta=2.45*Pi/180;
A=Exp[-2*(x^2+y^2)/100^2];
OmegaC=(0.3*gamma)*Exp[-2*(x^2/cv^2+(Mu+y Cos[Theta]+(z-L/2)Sin[Theta])^2/(ch^2(1-x^2/cv^2)))];
OmegaD=(0.3*gamma)*Exp[-2*(x^2/cv^2+(Mu+y Cos[Theta]+(z-L/2)Sin[Theta])^2/(ch^2(1-x^2/cv^2)))];

pde={D[a[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*S[z,t]+0.5*I*OmegaD*c[z,t]+(I*detund-0.5*gamma41)*a[z, t],
D[b[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*P[z,t]+0.5*I*OmegaC*c[z,t]+(I*detunp-0.5*gamma31)*b[z, t],
D[c[z,t],t]*(10^6)==0.5*I*b[z,t]*OmegaC+0.5*I*a[z,t]*OmegaD+(I*detunc-0.5*gamma21)*c[z,t],
D[P[z,t],z]+1/u*D[P[z,t],t]==I*alpha*gamma31/(2L)*b[z,t],
D[S[z,t],z]+1/u*D[S[z,t],t]==I*alpha*gamma41/(2L)*a[z,t]};

bc={P[0,t]==A*Boole[10<=t<=30],P[z,0]==0,S[0,t]==S[z,0]==0,b[z,0]==a[z,0]==c[z,0]==0};

mol[n_Integer, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> 
{"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" ->n, "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
mol[tf:False|True,sf_:Automatic]:={"MethodOfLines","DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"->
{tf,"ScaleFactor"->sf}}

solns = ParametricNDSolve[{pde, bc}, {P, S, a, b, c}, {z, 0, 4000}, {t, 0, 60}, {x, y}, 
Method -> Union[mol[True, 30], mol[350, 4]]];
expr1 = Sum[Abs[P[x, y][0, t] /. solns]^2, {x, -100, 100, 100}, {y, -100, 100, 100}]; 
// AbsoluteTiming
expr2 = Sum[Abs[P[x, y][4000, t] /. solns]^2, {x, -100, 100, 100}, {y, -100, 100, 100}]; 
// AbsoluteTiming
expr3 = Sum[Abs[S[x, y][4000, t] /. solns]^2, {x, -100, 100, 100}, {y, -100, 100, 100}]; 
// AbsoluteTiming

(*{329.435874, Null}*)
(*{335.286255, Null}*)
(*{333.557249, Null}*)

Plot[{expr1, expr2, expr3}, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

with the results:

[image]

However, each expr(1.2.3) require about **five minutes** to finish, but it's not the worst!

Because I think I need about 15 points for both x and y in order to get a more real simulation of my study. In other words, there are totally 225 points need to be solved, which is insane and time-consuming.

**1.** Is there any way to quickly get the results I want?

**2.** Also, I would like to abandon the values outside the range of radius (for x^2+y^2>=100^2) like:

```
expr2 = Sum[Abs[P[x, y][4000, t] /. solns]^2, {x, -100, 100, 100}, {y, -100, 100, 100}]
*If[x^2+y^2<=100^2,1,0];
```

Set those values to zero. 
But I think it would do some extra calculation instead of neglecting those points. How can I avoid it?

Really need any help and suggestions!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no well-posed question in this post; the OP is simply begging for somebody to act as a free coding service.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Okay thanks, I'm trying to simply my question for a specific way.

Comment: What is `mol`?  Your code doesn't run without it.

Comment: @CHrisK Okay, I edited my post already.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you - I don't use `ParametricNDSolve` myself.  A few ideas: could you live with a coarser spatial discretization?  Does evaluating each of `expr1`, `expr2`, and `expr3` resolve the PDE?  If so, that'll be inefficient.  For faster plotting, see my question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128731/plot-1d-slice-of-2d-interpolatingfunction).

Comment: Well, this question will probably be closed because it is too localized, still, here's some suggestion. For the **1**st part of the question, as shown in your previous question, obtaining a correct solution for your PDE system is already a bit challenging, so I think it's hard to speed up the PDE solving by improving your code only. It's more realistic to improve the model if possible. However, the **2nd** part of the question is simple, you just need `Sum[If[x^2 + y^2 <= 100^2, Abs[P[x, y][4000, t] /. solns]^2, 0], {x, -100, 100, 
  100}, {y, -100, 100, 100}]`.

Comment: @xzczd Really appreciate you reply. I'm thinking right now how to make it not much terrible because the model can't be simplified more.

Comment: @Chrisk Thanks for the link! I'm trying to rewrite my code by adjusting an acceptable spatial discretization. Also, let MMA solve it just once for obtaining three different expr. It's saving about 2/3 of time.